# How to redirect http://mydomain/blog/blahblah/ to http://mydomain/blahblah/ in wordpress htaccess?

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, apache

I would like the htaccess rewrite rule to compare to IIS rewrite rule I tried which doesn't seem to work:

```
<rule name="rewrite /blog/">
     <match url="^blog/([_0-9a-zA-Z\-]+)/$" />
     <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}/" />
 </rule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a WordPress question. Anyway …

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
```